# running weka over a large arff dataset file

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka, information-retrieval, arff

I am having an `arff` file that contains `700 entries`, each of `42000+ features` for a NLP related project. Right now the format is in dense format, but the entries can be reduced substantially, if sparse representation is used.
I am running on a `core 2 duo machine with 2 GB RAM`, and I am getting `memory out of range eception`, in spite of increasing the limit till 1536 MB.

Will it be of any advantage if I convert the arff file to a sparse representation or shall I need to run my code on a much more powerful machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the internal data structure of the algorithm and how the data can be processed (incrementally or all in memory) it will need more memory or not. So the memory you will need depends on the algorithm.

So sparse representation is easier for you because it is compact, but, as fas as I know, the algorithm will need the same amount of memory to create the model from the same dataset. The input should format be transparent to the algorithm.